# IE 11 select dropdown is slow after select an option

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

We have several select dropdowns in JSP pages.All of them function well in Chromes,Firefox and IE 9.

The odd is in IE11, the page got stucked after I selected an option in one of the selects while others worked well

I have eliminated the possibility of too many options in the select list by populating the select with less options, page still get stucked after selecting one option

Anyone can help ?

Tks

Comment: can you create a fiddle or codepen

Comment: Post the code here as a runnable snippet.